# Devide info which i get from using simple html dom library

Tags: php, html

So here is a shorter part of code.

```
include('simple_html_dom.php'); 

//load HTML file
$html = file_get_html('www.csfd.cz-film-2294-vykoupeni-z-veznice-shawshank-videa-.txt');  

//with simple_html_dom i search for data-truncate*="60"
$ret = $html->find('span[data-truncate*="60"] a'); 

$actors = array();
//i just print down all result of this search with <span data-truncate="60"> 
foreach ($ret as $reziser) {
    $rezia[] = $reziser->innertext;
    }
    echo "<br/> REZIA: <br/>";   
    echo "$rezia[0] <br/>";
    echo "$rezia[1] <br/>";
    echo "$rezia[2] <br/>";
    echo "$rezia[3] <br/>";
    echo "$rezia[4] <br/>";
```

, i also try to comment it in english a bit. My problem is that more things have same span () 
If you check HTML of this page (http://www.csfd.cz/film/2294-vykoupeni-z-veznice-shawshank/videa/)  and search for  you are gonna find something like this: http://pastebin.com/qrB5ejFK problem of it is that more different category using same span (Režie,Předloha,Scénář,Kamera,Hudba).RIght now i just search for this span and can print it out or save it to database but I need to devide result of my search depend on that categories (every  in this part of code is name of category and i need to divide result between them)

I hope you know what i am speaking about. Anyway thanks for helping me with my problem

Answer (score 0):

You can get the parent of an html element with .. parent() function !

You can do something like that :

```
foreach ($ret as $reziser) {
   //get the <div> wrapping the <span> wrapping the <a>
   $parent = $reziser -> parent() -> parent();
   //get the h4 element containg the category
   $category_element = $parent -> find('h4');
   //get the category
   $category = $category_element[0] -> innertext;
   //use the category as the key of your array enters
   $rezia[$category] = $reziser -> innertext;
}
```

This is just an example how to get the category. I didn't really understand what you really wanted, adapt the code to your needs.

Hodně štěstí !